# getting service unavailable and internal server error and JSONDecodeError at /pay/ while integrating phonepe in my django project

Tags: json, django, phonepe

this is my code please check it once
I am getting error at pay function  of this code and at this line  responseData = response.json()

```
def calculate_sha256_string(input_string):
    # Create a new SHA-256 hash object
    sha256 = SHA256.new()
    # Update hash with the encoded string
    sha256.update(input_string.encode('utf-8'))
    # Return the hexadecimal representation of the hash
    return sha256.hexdigest()

def base64_encode(input_dict):
    # Convert the dictionary to a JSON string
    json_data = jsons.dumps(input_dict)
    # Encode the JSON string to bytes
    data_bytes = json_data.encode('utf-8')
    # Perform Base64 encoding and return the result as a string
    return base64.b64encode(data_bytes).decode('utf-8')

def pay(request):
    MAINPAYLOAD = {
        "merchantId": "PGTESTPAYUAT",
        "merchantTransactionId": shortuuid.uuid(),
        "merchantUserId": "MUID123",
        "amount": 10000,
        "redirectUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/return-to-me",
        "redirectMode": "POST",
        "callbackUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/return-to-me",
        "mobileNumber": "9999999999",
        "paymentInstrument": {
            "type": "PAY_PAGE"
        }
    }
    # SETTING
    INDEX = "1"
    ENDPOINT = "/pg/v1/pay"
    SALTKEY = "099eb0cd-02cf-4e2a-8aca-3e6c6aff0399"
    base64String = base64_encode(MAINPAYLOAD)
    mainString = base64String + ENDPOINT + SALTKEY
    sha256Val = calculate_sha256_string(mainString)
    checkSum = sha256Val + '###' + INDEX
    print("Checksum:", checkSum)
    # Payload Send
    headers = {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-VERIFY': checkSum
    }
    payload = {
        'request': base64String
    }
    print("Sending request to PhonePe API:")
    print("URL:", 'https://api-preprod.phonepe.com/apis/pg-sandbox/pg/v1/pay')
    print("Headers:", headers)
    print("Payload:", payload)
    response = requests.post('https://api-preprod.phonepe.com/apis/pg-sandbox/pg/v1/pay', headers=headers, json=payload)
    print("Raw Response Content:")
    print(response.text)
    responseData = response.json() #getting error here
    print("Response from PhonePe API:")
    print(responseData)

    # Print the raw response content

    redirect_url = responseData['data']['instrumentResponse']['redirectInfo']['url']
    print("Redirect URL:", redirect_url)

    return redirect(redirect_url)

def payment_return(request):

    INDEX = "1"
    SALTKEY = "099eb0cd-02cf-4e2a-8aca-3e6c6aff0399"
    form_data = request.form
    form_data_dict = dict(form_data)
    # respond_json_data = jsonify(form_data_dict)
    # 1.In the live please match the amount you get byamount you send also so that hacker can't pass static value.
    # 2.Don't take Marchent ID directly validate it with yoir Marchent ID
    if request.form.get('transactionId'):
        request_url = 'https://api-preprod.phonepe.com/apis/pg-sandbox/pg/v1/status/PGTESTPAYUAT/' + request.form.get('transactionId')
        sha256_Pay_load_String = '/pg/v1/status/PGTESTPAYUAT/' + request.form.get('transactionId') + SALTKEY
        sha256_val = calculate_sha256_string(sha256_Pay_load_String)
        checksum = sha256_val + '###' + INDEX
        # Payload Send
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-VERIFY': checksum,
            'X-MERCHANT-ID': request.form.get('transactionId'),
            'accept': 'application/json',
        }
        response = requests.get(request_url, headers=headers)
        #print(response.text);
    return render('main/try.html', page_respond_data=form_data_dict, page_respond_data_varify=response.text)
```

this is my code

i tried everything i just want to it to open the payment screen in front of me i dont know if the error is from my side or from phonepe side  it is showing the error is in this line    responseData = response.json()

Comment: Please format your code properly. [edit] your code, select the code fragments and click on the "Code sample" button (`{}`) to format the code.

Comment: done please check it now

Comment: Share the full traceback. Normally the Django error page has a function to turn the error in a text format that includes settings, traceback, etc.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIL2b.png please check this image

Comment: the image only shows the *top* of the traceback, and moreover, images of code/errors/data are a [*very* bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/67579).

Comment: i dont think that pic contain anything personal

Comment: it doesn't. It just contains not the entire traceback, only the top of the stack, it can not be copied easily, it can not be searched, it takes more bandwidth, it can be blocked by proxies, people that are visually impaired can not let the screenreader read it, the host for the image can eventually discontinue, etc.

Comment: but you are again only showing the *top* of the traceback whereas in order to bugfix effectively the entire traceback often provides a lot more data to bugfix the problem